# Python - while loop files exists in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to check in a while loop if files exist in directory, but I haven't idea. I think is easy but I have problem.

```
root_path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Files/'
date_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

if not os.listdir(root_path):
    print("Directory is empty")
else:
    print("Directory is not empty")
    cmd = 'scp ' + root_path + '*.sql ...'
    ret1, status1 = tools.cmd(cmd)
    print('ret1: ' + ret1)

    while fileExists in root_path do :
```

Comment: To check if a path (file or directory) exists, use `while pathlib.Path(my_file_path).exists(): ...`. Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to execute a block of code while a file exists in your `root_path` directory?

In this case your while clause should be

```
while os.listdir(root_path):
    your_code_here
```

In this case `your_code_here` will be executed while the `root_path` has at least one file in there.

Be careful with this approach, because you might get into a perpetual while loop here